# FastAPI Python Try: Except: always return Except

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I am trying to insert building data to MongoDB using FastAPI:

```
@router.post("/add_building")
async def post_building(building: BuildingPayloadSchema):
try:
    result = await mongodb_connector.add_building(building)
except:
    result = f"Something went wrong {HTTPStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY}"
return result
```

Functions that connect to MongoDB and insert data looks like this:

```
 def connect(self):
    self._client = MongoClient(self._mongo_url)
    print("MongoDB connected...")
    self._db = self._client[self._db_name]
    print(f"{self._db_name} database has been created...")
    self._collection = self._db[self._collection_name]
    print(f"Building collection has been created...")
    

def add_building(self, building_data):
    building_data = json.dumps(building_data.__dict__)
    building_data = json.loads(building_data)
    insert_to_mongo = self._collection.insert_one(building_data)
    return insert_to_mongo
```

As I checked building data saves correctly to MongoDB, but post still returns except.

Comment: If you want to know what's wrong, don't just use `except:` - use `except Exception as e:`, then look at what `e` is - it's trying to tell you _what went wrong_. If you ignore the exception and just catch everything without looking at it, it'll just be guessing; you have an exception that says what the error was - look at it. (or don't catch it and it'll bubble up properly).

Comment: Seems like you would be better off just letting the exception propagate. Do you really want the caller to have to check if `post_building` returns a valid piece of data or an error message?

Comment: So when I modified except to `except Exception as e:` and `print(dir(e))` I get this in docker console:
`['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', 'args', 'with_traceback']`

Comment: Python is throwing exception because response is not like BuildingPayloadSchema?

Comment: Why are you printing `dir(e)` rather than `e`? To be honest I'd just outright remove the try/except block for now - if there's an error you want to ignore, then catch that _specific_ error and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution:

1. add_building function also need to be async so I modified it:

   ```
    async def add_building(self, building_data):
        building_data = json.dumps(building_data.__dict__)
        building_data = json.loads(building_data)
        insert_to_mongo = self._collection.insert_one(building_data)

        return True
   ```

2.I modified post function:

```
@router.post("/add_building")
async def post_building(building: BuildingPayloadSchema):
  try:
    await mongodb_connector.add_building(building)
    result = f"Building has been added succesfully... Status code: {HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED}"
  except:
    result = f"Something went wrong... Status code: {HTTPStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY}"
return result
```